# Is there a font size ratio between iPad and iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, fonts

I designed an App for a client for the iPhone. They want to create the App for iPad. If the font size is say 12pt on the iphone does the font double in size on the ipad? Is there an exact ratio between the font size on the iPhone and iPad? Their writers want to use the "exact" size of the font that will be on the iPad, I think it's to see what fits and how it will flow. Thanks!

Comment: Might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450522/iphone-calculating-the-font-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a default ratio that I have found, but I would recommend 18

Comment: Thanks!!! It was good to give them something concrete. There is always an issue when people want the layout in Word to mimic apps and web pages in general.